# Automatic rebase to drop a commit that modifies a file?

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-commit, git-rewrite-history

I'm new to git rebase and doing something a bit wacky and stupid.
So let's say I have these commits which all modify the same file `file.txt`

`a -> b -> c -> d -> e`

I want to just remove commit `c`.

My strategy for this is to rebase `b` onto `d`, keeping `d`'s changes so it reads like this

`a -> b -> d -> e`

I'm trying to do this with this command

```
git rebase --rebase-merges --onto c^ c
```

This results in a failed merge, I've also tried it with `-s ours` but that fails as well.

This works when each commit modifies a different file, however.

What should I do to satisfy this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you're almost certainly getting a conflict because there's really a conflict, and there isn't a way to avoid dealing with this.  You'll have to resolve the conflict and then run `git rebase --continue`.

This works when each commit modifies a different file because commits that touch different files don't usually conflict (unless there's a rename or copy).

Comment: Bah! Okay, that tracks. I want to run this automatically in a script, but that will work